# Release build vs flash build?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, starling-framework

i'm using Starling and I've built up my game in the flash IDE. I can test it on my phone, everything is ok. Now I read on the [starling wiki](http://wiki.starling-framework.org/manual/performance_optimization) that for better performance I need to build a "real" release build and that the published one from Flash CC isn't the optimized one?
If I understand correctly, how can I transform my build from flash CC to a true release build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to building it using Flash Builder or FlashDevelop, if you have the Flex SDK (which you should have if you've installed either of those two programs - if not, you can download it from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html), in the `bin` folder, you can find the `optimizer.exe` command line tool.

What it does is remove trace statements, debugging code (and symbols) and unnecessary metadata - which I think is mostly what a "release" build does. To use it, build your SWF with Flash CC, then go to the Flex SDK bin folder and, in your command line, type:

```
optimizer -keep-as3-metadata Bindable Managed ChangeEvent NonCommittingChangeEvent Transient 
    -input PATH/TO/SWF/input_swf 
    -output PATH/TO/SWF/output_swf
```

You can get more info on it here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7ff6.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ad9

Try and look into a proper coding environment though, rather than doing it straight from Flash CC. Personally I prefer FlashDevelop (http://flashdevelop.org/) - it's free, quick, and switching from debug to release is simple. Flash Builder has the edge when it comes to iOS publishing though, and if you have the Creative Cloud membership, you have it anyway (otherwise it's paid). It's also cross platform, whereas FlashDevelop is Windows-only.

Answer (score 0):

I run the automated release build process using Flash Builder in `Project->Export Release Build`. Or you can run an Ant build (also using Flash Builder/Eclipse).

But as far as doing it from the flash IDE, I'm not sure if that exact process exists. You can alter some of the advanced settings in `File->Publish` such as Omit trace statements (checked), permit debugging (unchecked), which is partially what the release build does.

Also for a mobile project with AIR there are options using Flash Builder under configurations for a Fast Build or a Standard Build.

***Fast Build***

- packaging takes several seconds, application runs significantly slower than a release build

***Standard Build***

- packaging takes several minutes, application performance is similar to a release build

Comment: I tried that in flash builder but I have assets attached from the libraries, it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Did you import those libraries into your flash builder project? That would be from `Project->Properties->Build Path`

Answer (score 0):

There are several types of builds for AIR mobile apps:

- Debug (Android)

  - CPU-intensive tasks take substantially longer in this build type.
- Fast Debug (iOS)

  - This type of debug build is incredibly slow. At best, you are looking at 10fps. This is because you are running your app in a virtual machine that is running your code as AS3 (the final app is cross-compiled to Objective-C). The benefit to this type of build is that it compiles in seconds
- Standard Debug (iOS)

  - This type of debug build is similar to an Android debug in terms of performance. CPU-intensive tasks will be substantially slower. This will take anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 minutes depending on how good your computer is. This code is cross-compiled to Objective-C, although the compiler does not run it through any optimizations
- Release (Android & iOS)

  - This is the build type you submit to the App Store or Play Store. Neither will accept a non-release build (non-release builds are signed using different certificates). This is the best performance you will get with your app as-is and will take a 3-30 minutes to cross-compile for iOS (depending on computer). Additionally, there are several options when building here:

    - Captive Runtime (Android)

      - This will bundle the AIR runtime with your app. It will add ~8-9MB of weight to your APK, but it won't require the user to install the Adobe AIR app to run it. You should **always** use Captive Runtime so that the user doesn't have to install a second app and your know what version of the AIR Runtime your app is running on.
    - Ad Hoc (iOS)

      - This type of build is meant for testing a release-quality build and can be distributed to non-development devices that are located on the Ad Hoc Mobile Provisioning Profile you created in the Apple Dev Portal
    - App Store (iOS)

      - This is the only build type that Apple will accept for the App Store. Any other build type will be automatically rejected. It cannot be installed on any device unless it comes from the App Store. Must use an App Store Mobile Provisioning Profile created in the Apple Dev Portal. No performance differences between this and Ad Hoc (same exact build, just different signature)